# How to capitalize the first letter of words in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, string, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to capitalize the first letter of certain words in my SQL qwery in Snowflake.

I am currently using this function:

```
SELECT ...
    case when FLAG1 is null then upper(FLAG2) else FLAG1 END as STATUS,
...;
```

The `UPPER()` function however renders all my `FLAG2` words to be fully capitalized. Anyone know how to capitalize the first letter of words in Snowflake?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [initcap()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/initcap.html) function, it returns the input string (expr) with the first letter of each word in uppercase and the subsequent letters in lowercase.

If you want only first letter in a string to be capitalized, ignoring word delimiters (i.e. the input expression is treated as a single, continuous word), specify empty string as delimiters parameter

```
INITCAP( str, '')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT column1, IFF(column1, UPPER(SUBSTRING(column2,1,1)) || LOWER(SUBSTRING(column2,2)), column2) 
FROM VALUES 
    (true,'all_lower'),
    (true, 'ALL_UPPER'),
    (true, 'mIxEd'),
    (false,'all_lower'),
    (false, 'ALL_UPPER'),
    (false, 'mIxEd');
```

which can be unpacked a little to see the parts at work.

```
SELECT column1 as flag
     ,column2 as orig
     ,UPPER(SUBSTRING(column2,1,1)) || LOWER(SUBSTRING(column2,2)) as first_upper
     ,IFF(flag, first_upper, orig)
FROM VALUES 
    (true,'all_lower'),
    (true, 'ALL_UPPER'),
    (true, 'mIxEd'),
    (false,'all_lower'),
    (false, 'ALL_UPPER'),
    (false, 'mIxEd');
```

which gives:

```
FLAG    ORIG        FIRST_UPPER   IFF(FLAG, FIRST_UPPER, ORIG)
TRUE    all_lower   All_lower     All_lower
TRUE    ALL_UPPER   All_upper     All_upper
TRUE    mIxEd       Mixed         Mixed
FALSE   all_lower   All_lower     all_lower
FALSE   ALL_UPPER   All_upper     ALL_UPPER
FALSE   mIxEd       Mixed         mIxEd
```