# How to uppercase first letter (without changing the others) in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, uppercase

I am aware of [INITCAP()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/initcap.html) and [this *similar* question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66588994/how-to-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-words-in-snowflake), but my question is different:

How can I uppercase the first letter ***only*** in a given string, *and leave the rest of the string untouched?*

INITCAP() can be made to uppercase the first letter only -- however, it will lowercase *everything else*, as mentioned in the documentation:

> `<delimiters>` specified as an empty string (i.e. '') instructs INITCAP to ignore all delimiters, including whitespace characters, in the input expression (i.e. the input expression is treated as a single, continuous word). The resulting output is a string with the first character capitalized (if the first character is a letter) **and all other letters in lowercase.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

another option is

`UPPER(LEFT(my_string,1))||SUBSTR(my_string,2)`

and if we use the same whitespace pattern, would win the code golf by 1:

`INSERT(my_string,1,1,UPPER(LEFT(my_string,1)))`

Comment: Oh yes, this is much cleaner & easier to read than using `INSERT()`! 

Answer (score 2):

Managed to do it using a few string manipulations:

```
SELECT INSERT(my_string, 1, 1, UPPER(LEFT(my_string, 1)));
```

`UPPER(LEFT(my_string, 1))` will extract the first letter of the string, and uppercase it.

[INSERT()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/insert.html) will replace a portion of the string with something else -- in this case, the first letter will be replaced with its uppercase version.